# .htaccess: 301 redirect not working in .htaccess in rewritten root path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a domain called `example.com` which points to `/public_html/` on my server.

In `/public_html/.htaccess` I have the following code to change the root path for my domain `example.com` to `/public_html/example_path/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule !example_path/ /example_path%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This is working very well.

Now, I want to redirect `example.com/test.png` to `example.com/images/test.png`. To do this, I'm using the following code in `/public_html/example_path/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /test.png /images/test.png
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working, there's no redirection. The redirect is only working if I put the code in `/public_html/.htaccess` but not in `/public_html/example_path/.htaccess`.

Why that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `/public_html/.htaccess` have redirect rule before `example_path` rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^test\.png$ /images/test.png [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !example_path/ /example_path%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Note that you cannot have image redirection rule inside `/example_path/.htaccess` because your image URL doesn't have `/example_path/`.

Comment: The redirect rule is working inside `/public_html/.htaccess`. But I want to have it to work inside `/public_html/example_path/.htaccess`.

Comment: `Redirect 301 /example_path/test.png /example_path/images/test.png` seems to work.

Comment: Yes obviously because now your URL has `/example_path/`.

Comment: Is it possible to use a wildcard instead of add a leading `/example_path/` to every rewrite rule?

Comment: Or, is it possible to "tell" `/public_html/example_path/.htaccess` that it's already in the root path and there's no path above?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question

Comment: In my rewrite rule I have to take `/example_path/test.png` instead of just `/test.png` because `/public_html/example_path/.htaccess` "knows" that the root path is on `/public_html/`. It there a way to tell `/public_html/example_path/.htaccess` that it's already on the root path. So I would be able to use `/test.png` instead of `/example_path/test.png` in my rewrite rules. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: See I suggested `RewriteRule ^test\.png$ /images/test.png [L,NC,R=301]` which is going to be same even if you use it in site root .htaccess or `example_path/.htaccess`. Just remember that site root one will redirect `example.com/image.png` but other one will redirect `example.com/example_path/image.png`